# How to use keyword 'columns' in pandas dataframe corretly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

If got a (50, 227) list of Values, which looks sth like:

```
[['/home/Desktop/t1.wav', 54 ,0.3, 0.5,.....,0.65], ...   
 ['/home/Desktop/t1.wav', 34, 0.5, 0.12, ... 0.59]]
```

And a list (227,) called Header

```
['path', 'segment', 'val_1','val_2', .... , 'val_n']
```

Now I want to create a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(Values, columns=Header)
```

The result is a [50 rows x 454 columns] Dataframe, where the 1st 227 columns are NaN.

```
    0   1   2   3   4  ...   z_cro83   z_cro84   z_cro85   z_cro86    z_cro9
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  ...  0.788452  0.708961  0.225294  0.861295  0.019912
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  ...  0.470561  0.785957  0.340802  0.337194  0.655845
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  ...  0.704172  0.308564  0.314529  0.018060  0.480141
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  ...  0.315092  0.325211  0.447381  0.377797  0.562558
4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  ...  0.793205  0.591529  0.899664  0.610295  0.622699
```

How can create the Frame without the 226 NaN columns ?

Comment: The usage is correct. Maybe there is some odd data hiding? Try running `np.asarray(Values)` to see if it produces a (50, 227) array or if there is a row that doesn't have the correct size.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: to check pandas version: `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: header =(227,)  Values(50, 227). Additional Information: If I dont add the header, everthing is fine.

Comment: The Error occurs from df.append(list). It has nothing to do with the key word 'columns'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of the 'keyword' columns is correct !

However my code included the line:

```
data_frame = data_frame.append(previous_frame)
```

I have no Idea why. But changing this line to just:

```
data_frame.append(previous_frame)
```

Made All the difference.

Comment: I assume you have accessed the file and written to it several times. I had a problem when I did this namely, it used a new column for the index and that column was written out and then read as a column when I accessed again. Use: `index_col` when reading the in the file.